# Drawing Line Starting/Ending at Pre-Existing Points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, editing, polyline-creation

I am trying to create a editing condition with a error message.
The condition is while drawing a new line feature, line should start and end at pre-existing point feature. If user try to start or end line at any other place other than these points, it should show an error message.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353749/adding-constrain-check-after-adding-first-point-of-line-and-after-last-point-of